# Issues when loading a sequential model in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, supervised-learning, image-classification

I had trained and saved the following sequential architecture

```
model = Sequential([layers.Resizing(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE), # Resize of the image 
layers.Rescaling(1./255), # Image rescaling of a factor 1./255
layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu',
padding = 'same', input_shape=(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,3)),
layers.Dropout(0.2),
layers.BatchNormalization(),
layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3),
activation='relu', padding = 'same'),
layers.BatchNormalization(),
layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3),
activation='relu', padding = 'same'),
layers.BatchNormalization(),
layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3),
activation='relu', padding = 'same'),
layers.BatchNormalization(),
layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
layers.Flatten(),
layers.Dropout(0.2),
layers.Dense(300, activation='relu'),
layers.Dense(150, activation='relu'),
layers.Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax')])

EPOCHS = 50
BATCH_SIZE = 8

history = model.fit(x=train_batches, validation_data=validation_batches,
steps_per_epoch=len(train_batches),
validation_steps=len(validation_batches),
epochs=EPOCHS,
batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
model.save('my_model.h5')
```

when i load the saved model

```
model=tf.keras.models.load_model('my_model.h5')
```

this error occurre

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Antonio Di Stolfo\Desktop\nuova codici 3\pythonProject2\main.py", line 88, in <module>
     model=tf.keras.models.load_model('my_model.h5')
   File "C:\Users\Antonio Di Stolfo\Desktop\nuova codici 3\cnnalzheimer\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
   File "C:\Users\Antonio Di Stolfo\Desktop\nuova codici 3\cnnalzheimer\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional\base_conv.py", line 409, in _get_input_channel
     raise ValueError( ValueError: The channel dimension of the inputs should be defined. The input_shape received is (None, 224, 224, None), where axis -1 (0-based) is the channel dimension, which found to be `None`.
```

Does anyone of you know how to solve this error or how to define the channel dimension of the inputs?

I tried to load a saved model but occurred an error

Comment: probably you should `unsqueeze` to create a channel dimension

Comment: Since i'm a beginner in python, can you help me?

Comment: You can try `model = Sequential([layers.Resizing(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)` if black and white images or `model = Sequential([layers.Resizing(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)` if 3 color channels